# According to scriptures, how Bana lingas are formed in Narmada river bed?

Tags: scripture, shiva-lingam

For those who don't know what are Bana Lingas, they are self manifested lingams which can be found only in Narmada river bed. What is the reason for formation of those Bala Lingas and how those Lingas are formed according to scriptures?